# Adding unallocated space to Ubuntu partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I am trying to add the unallocated space to `/dev/sda5` as in below screenshot but unable to.

[gparted Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3hS4.png)

**P.S.:** I tried the below approaches but didn't work for me:

1. Right click on `/dev/sda6` and select Swapoff and delete it and then
   try to run the command:

   `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda5`

   but this throws a warning:

   `resize2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014) The filesystem is already 6264576
   blocks long.  Nothing to do!`
2. Right click on `/dev/sda5` and select Unmount. This throws an error:

   `Device is busy` which makes sense.

So what should be my approach (if there is any without using a LiveCD).

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use gparted. Boot from liveCD of Ubuntu and open Gparted.
Than unmount the partition you want to resize.

If the unallocated space is on left to the Partition than first you have to move Partition to the left of unallocated space. Read Gparted's instruction on moving partiton [here.](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-move-partition)

After you moved the Partition on left of unallocated space, right click on your partition and select "resize". And now you can expand your Partition size easily.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on sda6 and select swapoff, right click on sda4 and increase its size, right click on sda6 and move it all the way to the right, and finally right click on sda5 and increase its size.

Comment: Unfortunately the option to resize on sda4 is grayed out even after selecting swapoff for sda6

Comment: @PrabhatRatnala, you must be running 14.04 I'm guessing?  In anything newer, this should not be the case.